# How to apply Post Layout Effect to ConstraintLayout 2.0

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

As this is a new feature in constraintLayout 2.0 with Decorators and Layers animations are possible but I'm not able to find any built-in solution for this effect.

Can anybody help me with achieving the Decorators and Layers effects as shown in the picture.

Any sample or links are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any build in solution for it

Comment: @AntonisRadz, http://androidkt.com/new-features-in-constraintlayout-2-0/ see this..